# Rails: how to load local file into the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a file located in `/lib/dir/file.xml`

I'm trying to call it by:

```
file = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/dir/file.xml'))
```

But I get the error, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The file definitely exists.

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/dir/file.xml
```

I'm on rails 4 and Ruby 2 if it helps. How do I load this file?

Comment: try double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: I tried double quotes and it gives a new error: `NameError: uninitialized constant ModleName::RAILS_ROOT`

Comment: Is your file in `./lib/dir/file.xml` or `/lib/dir/file/xml`? Big difference.

Comment: I figured it out, see answer below.

Comment: try `file = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(Rails.root.join('lib/dir/file.xml')))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.

`RAILS_ROOT` is depreciated. You're supposed to use `Rails.root` instead.

So here's the solution for people who see this in the future:

```
root = Rails.root.to_s #make sure string    
file = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("#{root}/lib/dir/file.xml"))
```

Comment: Please replace the single quotes with double ones. Stack overflow is about copy pasting remember ? :)